# Verify the existence of files in a Microsoft Access database

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database that has a column full of file names.. Some of these files have been moved or deleted. I basically need to verify the existence of each file (10,000+ files).. Basically I need to:

1. Loop through the table column (MyFilesNames) & check if the file exists..
2. If the file exists then move the file to a new location (Z:\MyFiles\myfilename.pdf) & update the file name to the new location (Z:\MyFiles\myfilename.pdf)..

NOTE: The file names have many different extensions (.pdf, .jpg, .gif, .docx, .xlsx etc..)

**THIS IS MY CURRENT TABLE & FILES**

-FILE NAMES STORED IN THE DATABASE:

```
MyFilesNames:
Z:\Temp\1.pdf
Z:\Temp\2.jpg
Z:\Temp\3.gif
Z:\Temp\4.pdf 
Z:\Temp\6.pdf
```

-ACTUAL FILES STORED ON THE COMPUTER:

```
Z:\Temp\1.pdf
Z:\Temp\2.jpg
Z:\Temp\3.gif
Z:\Temp\4.pdf
Z:\Temp\5.pdf
```

**THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE**

-FILE NAMES STORED IN THE DATABASE:

```
MyFilesNames:
Z:\MyFiles\1.pdf
Z:\MyFiles\2.jpg
Z:\MyFiles\3.gif
Z:\MyFiles\4.pdf 
Z:\Temp\6.pdf
```

-ACTUAL FILES STORED ON THE COMPUTER:

```
Z:\MyFiles\1.pdf
Z:\MyFiles\2.pdf
Z:\MyFiles\3.pdf
Z:\MyFiles\4.pdf
Z:\Temp\5.pdf
```

Is anyone able to help me achieve this using Access 2007?

Comment: Please post the general outline of your Access program.  What have you tried, and what problem are you having?

Comment: Have a good look at Dir and FileSystemObject. I generally prefer FileSystemObject, see reference Windows Script Host Object Model.